# How can I reset my branch to a commit I created while in detached-HEAD mode?

Tags: git, git-reset, git-detached-head

I've got no idea what the Git graph looks like in this instance, so before I accidentally lose any code, I figure I'll ask for help.

I committed some code that broke things, so I checked out a previous commit to look at what went wrong.

```
commit 87dfs7f6d6fs8 (latest commit on master) 
commit 7fe7f86we6f8d6 <-- checked out this guy
```

However, I forgot to recheckout `master` to fix the problem, and instead fixed it in the detached-HEAD state.

So, now, my Git history looks something like this... (I guess)

```
commit 87dfs7f6d6fs8 (latest commit on master) 

  |--- commit 6f5dsf5d65f <-- New commit (currently checked out)
commit 7fe7f86we6f8d6 <-- checked out this guy
```

What I'd like to do is completely get rid of the topmost commit and keep the changes that I made. I think to do this I need to `reset --hard` to the commit hash I'm currently on, right?

So, it'd be:

```
git reset --hard 6f5dsf5d65f
```

Where `commit 6f5dsf5d65f` is the commit I did in the detached-HEAD state.  Is this right..?

Comment: What does git status say ?

Comment: Save all the commit hashes before you make any changes.
This way, you'll be able to recover the good commit (I believe, 6f5dsf)

Comment: @Andrew_Lvov `HEAD detached from 7fe7f86we6f`

Comment: @user3308774 What does `git branch` say? Also, how come the currently checked out commit is `7fe7f86we6f8d6` and not `6f5dsf5d65f`? Did you run `git checkout 7fe7f86we6f8d6` after creating commit `6f5dsf5d65f`?

Comment: @Jubobs Copy paste error. When I wrote the question, I just typed random junk as a commit ids rather than copying and pasting from my shell. So in my comment, I replaced the actual commit id, with the one I created when I made my question -- I just copied the wrong one. It should have read: `HEAD detached from 6f5dsf5d65f` as you expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What I'd like to do is completely get rid of the topmost commit [`87dfs7f6d6fs8`] and keep the changes that I made.

If I understand your problem correctly, you basically need to

1. stash uncommitted changes (if any),
2. make the `master` branch point to commit `6f5dsf5d65f` instead of `87dfs7f6d6fs8`,
3. pop the stash (if necessary).

---

Check whether you need to create a stash by running `git status`. If it tells you that you have a clean working state, run

```
git checkout master            # important!
git reset --hard 6f5dsf5d65f
```

Otherwise, run

```
git stash save 
git checkout master            # important!
git reset --hard 6f5dsf5d65f
git stash pop
```

Note that, in either case, you need to check out `master` before you can reset it; running `git reset` while in detached-HEAD state would only move `HEAD`.